# Find the indices of a specific element in a 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I want to find a specific value's indices in a 2D matrix. For example there is a matrix such as:

```
A = 
    0 0 8 8 1
    0 6 7 1 1
    5 1 1 1 1
```

Here, I want to get the indices of "0". So, there should be an array like:

```
indices = [(1,1) (1,2) (2,1)]
```

How can I do that? I tried to use find() function but it just returns one coordinate. However, I want to get all coordinates of "0".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use two outputs for [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
[row,col] = find(A==0)
```

The single output you got was the linear index. This is the element number by counting down the columns e.g. for your  matrix these are the linear indices:

```
1  4  7  10
2  5  8  11
3  6  9  12
```

which you could also use to locate an element in a matrix (so for your example the zeros are at linear index `1`, `2` and `4`). But what you're asking for is the subscript index, for that you need to provide `find` with 2 output variables.

but if you want to get a matrix exactly like your `indices` you need to concatenate my `row` and `col` matrices:

```
indices = [row, col]
```